# Wordpress sliding drawer plugin doesn't stay closed after converting page to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-sliding-drawer-content-area/ on my Wordpress site that creates a drawer on the side for my widgets. It works perfectly fine on my local server.

Unfortunately, I have to convert each of the Wordpress pages into HTML pages for use on my client's intranet servers. That's when the drawer refuses to stay closed on page load unlike before.

Here's the js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   if(jQuery('#sod-drawer-plugin.left').length >0){
            var $handle = jQuery('#sod-drawer-plugin.left #sod-drawer-handle');
            var $plugin = jQuery('#sod-drawer-plugin.left');
            var $adjustment = (parseInt($handle.outerWidth())/2)-parseInt($handle.outerHeight())/2;
            if (jQuery.browser.msie){
                $plugin.css({
                        left:parseInt($plugin.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$plugin.outerWidth():0
                });
                $handle.css({
                        left:parseInt($plugin.css('left'),10) == 0 ? parseInt($plugin.outerWidth()-$adjustment):$plugin.outerWidth()
                });
                $handle.click(function(){
                    $plugin.animate({
                        left:parseInt($plugin.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$plugin.outerWidth():0
                    });
                    $handle.animate({
                        left:parseInt($plugin.css('left'),10) == 0 ? parseInt($plugin.outerWidth()-$adjustment):$plugin.outerWidth()
                    });
                });
            }else{
                $plugin.css({
                        left:parseInt($plugin.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$plugin.outerWidth():0
                });
                $handle.css({
                        left:parseInt($plugin.css('left'),10) == 0 ? parseInt($plugin.outerWidth()-$adjustment):$plugin.outerWidth()-$adjustment
                });
                $handle.click(function(){
                    $plugin.animate({
                        left:parseInt($plugin.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$plugin.outerWidth():0
                    });
                    $handle.animate({
                        left:parseInt($plugin.css('left'),10) == 0 ? parseInt($plugin.outerWidth()-$adjustment):$plugin.outerWidth()-$adjustment
                    });
                });
            }
   }
 });
```

And the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0088)./work-life-balance/enhance-your-professional-standing/ -->
<html lang="en-US"><!--<![endif]--><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Enhance Your Professional Standing | Staff Benefits and Work-life Initiatives</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" id="sod_drawer_css-css" href="./style(1).css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./sod_drawer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./saved_resource.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body class="page page-id-167 page-child parent-pageid-4 page-template-default">

    <div class="sod-drawer left" id="sod-drawer-plugin" style="left: -280px;"> <!--- This value changes to left:0px when loaded on the browser --->
        <div id="sod-drawer-handle" class="pull black rotate" style="left: 240px;">
            <div class="tag"><p>Contents</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="sod-drawer-inner">
                <div class="full" id="sod-drawer-1">
                    <div id="execphp-2" class="sod-drawer-widget widget_execphp">           
                        <div class="execphpwidget">
                            <div id="sidebar">
                                <h1><a href="./" title="Staff Benefits and Work-life Initiatives" rel="home">Staff Benefits and Work-life Initiatives</a></h1>
                                <div id="access" role="navigation" class="desc">
                                    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
                                        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
                                            <li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="./">Introduction</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-626" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-626"><a href="./epilogue/">Epilogue</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- #access -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not proficient with Javascript so a little explanation would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the jQuery script library loading properly? I am doubtful of the src URL of your script at the document head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
```

These URLs might be the problem. It may work correctly in your local server, but not on a live URL. You may need to change it to "/jquery.js" because the "." refers to the current directory. The "/" right at the start refers to the root URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
```

Please try it and let me know the result.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping! Though I kinda solved the problem by accident heh. The above code was saved through Chrome. If I saved it through FF (only with the drawer open) it would work again. Appreciate your help :)